# Regex expression to match only whole word

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following sample text

```
"dont pick descri@ption but pick @description only"
```

What regex expression will pick `@description` and leave out `descri@ption`?

I tried the following

`(?=\s)@\w+?(?=\W)`    --> doesn't pick either of them

`(?=\S)@\w+?(?=\W)`    --> picks both

`(?=\W)@\w+?(?=\W)`    --> picks both

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)@[^@\s]+`

Answer (score 2):

About the patterns you tried

- The first pattern does not match due to the `(?=\s)` which asserts what is directly on the right is a whitespace char. But the next being matched is a `@` so that assertion is false.
- The second and the third pattern match because the assertions `(?=\S)` and `(?=\W)` are both true for an `@` sign. Then this part `@\w+?(?=\W)` will match 1+ word chars and make sure that at the end there is a non word character which both match.

You could use a negative lookahead and lookbehind to assert what is on the left and right is not a non whitespace char.

Then use a negated character class to match not an `@` or a whitespace char

```
(?<!\S)@[^@\s]+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%40%5b%5e%40%5cs%5d%2b%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=dont+pick+descri%40ption+but+pick+%40description+only%0d%0atest+%40description%40abc)

If you want to match word characters instead:

```
(?<!\S)@\w+(?!\S)
```

Comment: Isn't `(?<=\s)` the same as `(?<!\S)`?

Comment: @ggorlen The difference is that the positive lookbehind `(?<=\s)` expects that there is a whitespace char on the left. The negative lookbehind expects that what is on the left is NOT a non whitespace char. See these examples https://regex101.com/r/daAKsk/1/ and https://regex101.com/r/VDpLnc/1/

Comment: Ah yeah these examples help. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen See the 2 examples in the previous comment that I just updated.

Comment: This matches 's: '@description' in  '@description@abc '. Do you mean to? The original question is not all that precise as to what the boundaries are.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Good point, I did not mean to match those as well. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?:(\A|\s))(@[^@\s]+)(?=(\Z|\s))
```

The '@' must be preceded by either the start of string or a space. Then it must be followed by one or more characters that are neither a space nor a '@'. Finally the string must be followed by either a space or the end of string.